# Check my proof of the "Boundedness theorem"

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

**Theorem**: *Let $f$ be continuous on a closed interval $[a, b]$. Then f is bounded on $[a, b]$.*

**Proof (*sketch*)**: Suppose $f$ is unbounded. Let's define the set $N$ containing those $x$ for which $f$ is bounded on [a, x). Since $f$ is continuous there is $\delta$ such that $f$ is bounded on $[a, a + \delta)$, so $N$ is *not empty*. Since $N$ is bounded by $b$, we take $sup = supN$ and appealing to continuity of $f$ show that $sup$ belongs to $N$ and if $sup < b$ there is some $\delta$ such that $f$ is bounded on $[a, sup + \delta)$, so $sup + \delta$ must be in $N$ (a contradiction).

Comment: Look more like a sketch of a proof to me, but otherwise it is ok.

Comment: I think that you will run into trouble when you attempt to formalize the statement "appealing to continuity of $f$ show that $sup$ belongs to $N$".

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, note that you are not really using that $[a,b]$ is closed.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Since $f$ is continuous, for some $\delta$, $f$ is bounded on $(sup - \delta, sup]$, hence $f$ is bounded on $[sup - \delta/2, sup]$. Since $sup - \delta/2$ is less then $sup$, $f$ is also bounded on $[a, sup - \delta/2)$, so on the whole interval $[a, sup]$.

Comment: @5xum: So changing $[a, x)$ to $[a, x]$ in the definition of $N$ is enough?

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was false. The problem you have here is that you claim $f$ is bounded on $(sup-\delta, sup]$, when you have not yet shown that $sup\in[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sketch looks fine for now, of course you will need to elaborate on some points, but it looks OK and it should go through. Be careful, though, as the closedness of the interval is vital and you must use it (see $1/x$ on $[-1,0)$) (also see the comment by  Martin Argerami on this topic) 2 minor points, though:

1) You do not need to work with reductio ad absurdum here. Just drop the "suppose $f$ is unbounded" at the beginning, and your proof will still hold. Basically, you first suppose $\not A$, then prove, $A$, then say "$A$ is in contradiction with $\not A$, therefore the original proposition of "$\not A$" is false, which means $A$ is true". I know this is just a minor complaint, but basically, it's simpler to just take the set $N$ and prove $N=[a,b]$, therefore proving $f$ is bounded.

2) Another, maybe simpler proof (this one DOES use contradiction): Suppose $f$ is unbounded. Then there exists a sequence $x_n$ on $[a,b]$ so that $|f(x_n)|>n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. Because $[a,b]$ is compact, $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence $x_{n_i}$, $i\in \mathbb N$ with limit $c$. Now, since $f$ is continuous, you know that

$$\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} f(x_{n_i})=f(\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} x_{n_i})=f(c),$$
however you also know that the limit does not exist. This is a contradiction, therefore $f$ cannot be unbounded.

Comment: I don't think that "the sketch is fine". As you show in 2, compacity is an essential ingredient in this proof.

Comment: True, but the sketch can help him prove that $f$ is bounded on every interval $[a,x]$ for $x<b$. Then it's not far to show that it's bounded on $[a,b]$. Therefore, I think the sketch is fine, but he will need to elaborate a few points. It's fine in the sense that it's not a dead end.